# What is the difference between right/left placement of column name in a WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

Both of the following queries return the same output but I'm curious whether there is underlying difference between these two syntaxes.

```
    SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE first_name = 'John';
```

and

```
    SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE 'John' = first_name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no semantic difference. It is purely a matter of style.

The first form is much more common, in my experience.

The order of `WHERE` clauses with respect to `AND` does not matter either.